# While i am using A.CallTo() method of FakeItEasy and using not a fake object inside it. It's throwing exception:

Tags: c#, unit-testing, fakeiteasy

Below code throwing exception at run time:

```
A.CallTo(() => myObject.Add(dummyobject)).Returns(result);
```

below is the exception:

> Object 'myObject' of type 'classType' not recognized as a fake object.'

where i can not create fake object of myObject.

here are the more details: myObject -> my class Object, and type is nothing but my class it can be anything like 'ABC'. A is a static class provided by FakeItEasy framework

Comment: you need to provide more details here. what is myObject? what type of it is? how are you creating fake object? what is A?

Comment: here are the more details: myObject -> my class Object, and type is nothing but my class it can be anything like 'ABC'.                                       A is nothing but a static class provided by FakeItEasy framework.

Comment: @GujjarG how did you initialize `myObject`? If you did `myObject = new classType()`, then your object isn't a fake and cannot be configure by FakeItEasy. You need to do `myObject = A.Fake<classType>()`. Also, I suggest you read the [documentation](http://fakeiteasy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/what-can-be-faked/) to ensure your type *can* be faked.

Comment: Thanks for the info Thomas, but i was searching work around for that only. Although there are some limitation that i can not create myObject using Fake.I am searching that i can use myObject = new classType() and fakeiteasy should not throw any exception, any work around.